# The reason of memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory

why does this code cause memory leak?

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("Program to illustrate memory leak via closure");
    window.onload=function outerFunction(){
        var obj = document.getElementById("element");
        obj.onclick=function innerFunction(){
        alert("Hi! I will leak");
        };
        obj.bigString=new Array(1000).join(new Array(2000).join("XXXXX"));
        // This is used to make the leak significant
    };
    </script>
    <button id="element">Click Me</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

it's listing 5 from here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

Comment: It explains it right under the code snippet.

Comment: thanks, but don't get it, and that is why I've asked a question here

Answer (score 0):

looks like modern browsers catch these leaks, explanation in 4 listing, need to read the full article

Comment: can't close question for some reason